# scale_fill_brewer((Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to plot twitter sentiment analysis using ggplot2.
the expected output is the image below.

[image]

**Script:-**

```
ggplot(sent_df, aes(x=polarity)) +
geom_bar(aes(y=..count.., fill=polarity)) +
scale_fill_brewer(palette="RdGy") +
labs(x="polarity categories", y="number of tweets") +
options(title = "Sentiment Analysis of Tweets \n(classification by polarity)",
     plot.title = theme_bw(base_size=12))
```

when run the above script im getting error as

```
   Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot
```

Please suggest me what was the mistake i am doing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you get the idea for the last two lines? They are simply wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible correct way:

```
    library(ggplot2)
    ggplot(mpg, aes(x=class)) +
            geom_bar(aes(y=..count.., fill=class)) +
            scale_fill_brewer(palette="RdGy") +
            xlab("polarity categories") + 
            ylab("number of tweets") +
            ggtitle("Sentiment Analysis of Tweets \n(classification by polarity)") + 
            theme_bw() + 
            theme(plot.title = element_text(size=12))
```